# Returning templated dependent types

Tags: c++, templates, dependent-type

Let's say that I create a template for a sized array:

```
template <int Size>
class SizedArray {
   private:
      std::vector<int> array_;
   public:
      SizedArray() {
         for (int i = 0; i < Size; ++i) {
            array_.push_back(0);
         }
      }
      ... // other methods
};
```

I would like to define a new function, `merge`, which creates a new `SizedArray` containing elements from two `SizedArray`s

```
template<typename SizeA, typename SizeB>      
SizedArray<SizeA + SizeB> merge(SizedArray<SizeA> a, SizedArray<SizeB> b) {
   // additional code
}
```

However, when I try to compile this code, I get an error saying "template argument 1 is invalid" (presumably because of the `SizeA + SizeB` portion of the return type). Is there a way to create a dependent return type that is the sum of the dependent types of the function's arguments?

Comment: Why are you using `std::vector` instead of `std::array` or a plain array for a fixed-size `array_`?

Comment: Fir things like sizes you should use `size_t` and not `int`. For one thing `size_t` is `unsigned`, because a size can never be negative. Also, the name `size_t` gives more information about the type to the reader about how variables of this type are used.

Comment: @anderas i'd guess heap vs automatic storage. I'm more curious why `: array_(Size)` isn't in an member initializer list rather than the for-loop.

Comment: @anderas Joachim WhozCraig Great recommendations. I appreciate the pointers. I'll update my actual code, but leave the code in the question as is so that the comments make sense for the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SizeA` and `SizeB` are `typename`s, not `int`s in your function declaration. You obviously can't add types, but if you declare the template parameters of the function as `int` things will work.